# T4 POCO template - deleting auto-generated .cs file in the .tt file

Tags: templates, entity-framework-4, poco, t4

I am modifying the "ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator" template to create my own POCO classes. My .tt file for my Model is called Model1.tt. When you expand Model1.tt you will see a file called Model1.cs, which contains some auto-generated "Fixup" code:

```
public class FixupCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    //Auto-generated code here
}
```

I don't need this Model1.cs file. Is it possible to modify the Model1.tt file so that it won't create the Model1.cs file at all?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to completely remove the file, but to remove the `FixupCollection` class you can just remove or comment out `WriteCustomObservableCollection();`. Note that you will have to modify the part of the template that generates the `FixupCollection`s for your POCO navigation properties too.

Comment: Yes - this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue - one solution is to utilize the class itself as a base class, etc.  Not exactly deleting it, I know, but I couldn't see a way to do it easily.

Comment: I also used this hack after trying every other thing... Still I think there is something that I can do to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Files are created using the EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager. On line #26 of tt file for types's you'll see it being initialized:

```
EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this);
```

You'll see everywhere it's used just for searching for "fileManager" in the file.

Comment: If you comment out fileManager throughout the Model1.tt file, then you will get a few errors and you won't get any entity generated.

Comment: I don't get a Model1.cs file generated when i run the template - only files that get generated are for the "real" entities. I'm guessing this file is getting generated due to a customization you made in the template.

Comment: Hmmm...I started over again. 1) I added ADO.NET Entity Data Model (Code Generation Strategy = None); 2) added "Add Code Generation Item..."; 3) added "ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator"; 4) commented out 'fileManager' in Model1.tt; 5) deleted all .cs files under Model1.tt then ran the Model1.tt template. Result: only Model1.cs is generated. No .cs files for each entity in my model are generated. However, Model1.cs contains the definitions for the entities.